# Remove par indent from environment

Tags: environments, indentation, framed

The real problem here is that I can't figure out how to modify an existing environment. The concrete thing I want to achieve follows below.

I'm pretty happy with what the [`framed`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/framed) package gives me with its `shaded*` environment. But I'd like to change two things:

1. The first paragraph in the environment should not start with indentation.
2. I want to rename the environment from `shaded*` to something else.

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{lipsum, xcolor, framed}
       \definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{.8}

   \begin{document}
       \begin{shaded*}
           \lipsum[1-2]
       \end{shaded*}
   \end{document}
   ```

[image]

Comment: to highlight code in a list, the lines have to be indented 8 spaces.  unfortunately, i don't know any way to do this except manually, line by line.

Comment: @barbarabeeton A trick we ascribe to David Carlisle: use `{}` to add the four blank spaces, then add a line with only one character flush left before the code; select the code again, press `{}` and remove the additional line.

Comment: @Sverre: See [Why do code snippets not work after lists?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1558/5764)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the trick of `\@afterheading` (simplified):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum, xcolor, framed}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{.8}

\newenvironment{blurb}
 {\begin{shaded*}\everypar={{\setbox0=\lastbox}\everypar{}}}
 {\end{shaded*}}

\begin{document}

\begin{blurb}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{blurb}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You mean that this code is taken from what LaTeX does after a heading?

Comment: @Sverre Yes, it's a nice trick that's also explained in the TeXbook. Since `\everypar` is invoked after the paragraph has been started and the indentation box has been inserted, `{\setbox0=\lastbox}` removes it (and `\box0` doesn't even change, because it's done in a group). Then `\everypar` is reinitialized to empty.

Answer (score 4):

Using `tcolorbox` for a change (for academic purposes).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{.8}

\newtcolorbox{fancypar}[1][]{
    colback=shadecolor,
    boxsep=6pt,
    parbox=false,
    arc=0pt,
    outer arc=0pt,
    nobeforeafter,
    frame hidden,
    enhanced jigsaw,
    breakable,
    before=\par\noindent%
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{fancypar}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{fancypar}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The following might be what you're after:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum, xcolor, framed}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{.8}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{myfancyshade}
  {\@nameuse{shaded*}\noindent\ignorespaces}
  {\@nameuse{endshaded*}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{myfancyshade}
  \lipsum[1-2]
\end{myfancyshade}
\end{document}
```

The old `shaded*` environment is invoked using `\@nameuse`, but using the traditional environment name works as well. Paragraph indentation is avoided via `\noindent`, and any spurious spaces is dropped using `\ignorespaces`.

Comment: What do you mean by "using the traditional environment name works as well"?